# Как настроить зависимости в WebStorm для работы с ember.js?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains, ember.js

Поставил ember-quickstart в **WebStorm** проекте и столкнулся с проблемой. При написании импортов IDE автоматически предлагает названия модулей из **node_modules**, а вот из **bower_components** никак не хочет. Указание в **Libraries** также не помогает, подскажите, как решить проблему?

Comment: у вас есть какие то модули в bower которых нет в node? они разве не синхронизируются?